# js: which is faster? array or object access

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, performance-testing

I have an array of approximately 19.000 items.

I'll have to access them by an arbitrary id at random (that is, there's no need to traverse the array)

I was just wondering if js con optimize the code if I use the id as the index of the array, or if there's any kind of trick or library to speed up these kind of things.

To be more precise, I'll have the results of an election in approximately 20k schools, and I'd like to know your advice about which one would be faster:

```
[
  {
    school_id: xx
    results: [
      {
        party_id: xx
        votes: xx
      }, [...]
    ]
  }, [...]
]

[   // use school_id as index to the array
  [
    {
      party_id: xx
      votes: xx
    }, [...]
  ], [...]
]
```

The question is if js is smart enough to optimize array random access.

And any tool you could advice me to use to test the performance would be much welcome

Comment: Write a test in jsperf

Comment: Arrays are actually objects, as well (hash tables). You can use either, it really doesn't matter. But if you choose to use an object, it won't have array methods (doesn't inherit from Array). I'm probably confusing you. Just use Arrays.

Answer (score 1):

These questions are always engine-dependent. In V8 (Google Chrome, Node.js):

Objects and Arrays are not radically different. For implementation simplicity, all objects have an external elements array where properties that are positive integers are stored.

So when you do `obj[5]`, it doesn't matter if `obj` is the Javascript Array object or any javascript object - it will access the object's external elements array.

So if you created an object like this:

```
var a = {
    a: 3,
    b: 4,
    c: {},

    5: 5,
    6: 6
};
```

The object layout will be:

```
[HiddenClassPointer, PropertiesArrayPointer, ElementsArrayPointer, TaggedSmallInteger(3), TaggedSmallInteger(4), JSObjectPointer]
```

Note how the named fields are stored side by side with the internal fields. If you now add any property after the fact, it will
go into the external properties array pointed by the second field instead of stored on the object directly.

The "fields" with the integer key would be in the external elements array pointed to by `ElementsArrayPointer` like this:

```
[HiddenClassPointer, TaggedSmallInteger(25), TheHolePointer, TheHolePointer, TheHolePointer, TheHolePointer, TheHolePointer, TaggedSmallInteger(5), TaggedSmallInteger(6), ...more hole pointers until 25 elements]
```

The 25 is length of the backing array. I will come back to that soon.

The hole pointer is needed to disambiguate between explicit undefined values given from the user and actual holes in the array. When you try to retrieve a[3], it will
return you `undefined` because there was a hole. So the actual hole object is not returned to user. So there are actually 3 different types of null :P

The initial length of 25 comes from the formula `(initial index + 1 ) + ((initial_index + 1 ) / 2) + 16` so `6 + 7/2 + 16 = 25`. You can see it in a [heap snapshot](http://jsfiddle.net/UGBkn/1/).

[image]

```
( 108 - 8 ) / 4 === 25
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a test using [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com).  You can test a number of different scenarios using it.